# Estimated runtime scheduling abstraction

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm writing priority scheduling abstraction code, in which I receive the number of processes as well as their runtimes and their priorities. The process with the highest priority runs first, then the next one. Runtime adds up like `runtime1 + (runtime1 + runtime2) + ...`.

It runs without error or warning when I execute it but it only receives values that I ask for and does not return anything. What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct process {
  int priority;
  int runtime;
} Process;

int main() {
  int numberOfProcess;
  int i;

  printf("enter process number\n");
  scanf("%d",&numberOfProcess);
  Process proc[numberOfProcess];

  for (i = 0; i < numberOfProcess; i++) {
    printf("Enter the process runtime\n");
    scanf("%d", &proc[i].runtime);
    printf("Enter the priority\n");
    scanf("%d", &proc[i].priority);
  }

  int done = 1;
  int index;
  int completedtimes[10];
  int usage;

  while (done > 0) {
    done = -1;
    int maxPriority = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < numberOfProcess; index++) {
      if (proc[index].priority > proc[maxPriority].priority)
        maxPriority = index;
      proc[maxPriority].priority = -1;
      usage += proc[maxPriority].runtime;
      completedtimes[maxPriority] = usage;

      for (index = 0; index < numberOfProcess; i++)
        if (proc[index].priority != -1)
          done = -1;
      for (index = 0; index < numberOfProcess; index++)
        printf("process %d completed at %d sec", index, completedtimes[index]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Didn't you already post this question?

Comment: I made it more format friendly,why though,is it forbidden to ask for help?

Comment: And I also removed the old one.

Comment: No need to delete the question. Edit into shape and it will be reopened if it fits the criteria.

Comment: Shouldn't you change your iterating variable names? Or close the outermost for loop before the inner ones?

Answer (score 1):

You have an endless loop in the first for-loop at loop level 2, look at the counter **index** and **i**

```
    while(done>0) {
        done=-1;
        int maxPriority=0;
        for(index=0;index<numberOfProcess;index++) {
            if(proc[index].priority>proc[maxPriority].priority)
                maxPriority=index;
            proc[maxPriority].priority=-1;
            usage+=proc[maxPriority].runtime;
            completedtimes[maxPriority]=usage;
            for(index=0;index<numberOfProcess;i++)
                if(proc[index].priority!=-1)
                    done=-1;
            for(index=0;index<numberOfProcess;index++)
                printf("process %d completed at %d sec", index, completedtimes[index]);
        }
    }
```

Btw. It will not work how wished because you use and reset **index** in different loop levels

Comment: In second for loop I apparently used index as counter and incremented i.I fixed that now and it now gives the content of the last printf function however it says "process 1 is completed in 4180741412seconds" which is absurd,is that some kind of ascii value?

Comment: No, that is because variable usage isn't initialized between declaration and usage. Replace **int usage;** with **int usage = 0;**.